# Error: No module named fileupload

Tags: django, file-upload, django-models, blueimp

I'm attempting to use this ported version of jQuery File Upload (https://github.com/sigurdga/django-jquery-file-upload). I placed the 'fileupload' directory in the root of the project (next my myapp, settings.py) and modified my urls.py file with `url(r'^upload/', include('fileupload.urls')),` and added `'fileupload',` to my `INSTALLED_APPS` setting in my settings.py file. When I try `python manage.py validate (OR shell OR syncdb)` I get this error: `Error: No module named fileupload`

Did I install the application wrong? I have PIL installed and obviously Django (1.4.1).

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Django 1.4, and you've installed the fileupload app in the same directory as the `settings.py`, then you probably need to use the path `myproject.fileupload` instead of `fileupload`.

```
# settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'myproject.fileupload',
    ...
)

# urls.py
url(r'^upload/', include('fileupload.urls'))
```

The alternative would be to move your `fileupload` app into the parent directory.